# Metadata file could not be found in C# app

Tags: c#, metadata, pdftron

I'm attempting to run a sample project associated with PDFTron's sample project "PDFViewWPF" located at: https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/downloads.html as the .Net 4.0+ library.

The project throws an error: `Metadata file "C:\...\...\Samples\PDFViewWPF\CS\bin\Debug\PDFViewWPFCS2015.dll" could not be found` on build.

Unsure on this error because dll's shouldn't be generated in the "bin\Debug" folder right?

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Does your solution only consists of one project, or are there more? From experience - something like this might happen if your build order is not right. Certain classes r refer to the DLL, which has not yet been built.

Comment: That's more than likely what the problem is. I'm in contact with the vendor for a solution. Will update.

Comment: There is no PDFViewWPF folder in the Samples folder of the PDFNet SDK. There is PDFViewWPFMVVMTest, PDFViewWPFSimpleTest, and PDFViewWPFTest. Are you running one of the samples from the SDK? Or is this your own project?